# PDO, MySQL SELECT statement returning boolean true?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Just using a SELECT in my MySQL statement, trying to get a column.

```
$last_visit = $db->prepare( 'SELECT `last_visit` FROM `visitors` WHERE `ip` = :ip' )
        ->execute( $arr_ip );
var_dump( $last_visit );
```

The output of var_dump is `bool(true)` instead of the data I need. Trying `->fetch()` only throws an error.

What can I do? This is holding up my whole project, and I can't figure out what's wrong no matter where I look. The correct data is in the database, the connection is correct and INSERT works.

Comment: What is the error thrown by `fetch()`?

Comment: Sorry, but I have a policy of downvoting questions which could be answered by simply taking a look at the manual, which just seems like laziness to me. SO should not be used as a replacement for reading readily available documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as said in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), `execute()` returns a boolean. take a look at the eamples for [fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to see how your should use PDO.

In your case, the code should look like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( 'SELECT `last_visit` FROM `visitors` WHERE `ip` = :ip' );
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $arr_ip);
$stmt->execute();
if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
  $last_visit = $row['last_visit'];
}else{
  // whatever you like to do if there's no result...
}
```

**EDIT:**
additional information in response to your comment:

For an `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, you can do a one-liner like your example, because you may not need the result (or rather just `true`/`false` to see if the request was successful).

For a `SELECT`, you need to `fetch()` the result. You can leave `bindParam()` out and give the params to execute, like you tried, but without a `fetch()`, you wont get your results.

Comment: Hmm. Can't believe I missed that. Guess when working with PDO before I'd never used SELECT with execute. Now I want to downvote my own question.

Comment: You had a bug in your example (`$sth->bind...` instead of `$stmt->bind...`), but I fixed it for you :-)

Comment: thans nikc, i missed that while copy&pasting from php.net to build the example suitable for the question ;)